# JavaScript, a good way to represent a float as color in a plot

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, colors

I am trying to create a plot using JavaScript (D3.js) and In every second I have new incomming point with label, this label is a float chosen randomly from a given interval.

I need to represent this label (float) with one given color so I get points with gradient colors, **Something like**:

[image]

I have tried this as far, but it don't give the expected result.

```
function float2color( label ) {
        var r = 255 - ( label / 8 * 255 | 0 ); 
            g = label / 8 * 255 | 0;  

        return '#' + 
            ( r ? ( r = r.toString(16), r.length == 2 ? r : '0' + r ) : '00' ) +
            ( g ? ( g = g.toString(16), g.length == 2 ? g : '0' + g ) : '00' ) + '00'
    }
```

**RESULT (not good))**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a linear color scale. This would replace your float2color function.

```
var color = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([min, max])
    .range(['blue', 'yellow']);
```

Then to actually get the color from the float,

```
color(float_value);
```

Note that `'blue'` and `'yellow'` can be given as hex representations as well. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear-scales